# Как вытащить слово из переменной

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго времени суток знатоки. Я новичок в программировании, и встретился с   проблемой, которую пока не знаю как решить, и надеюсь на Вашу помощь.
В переменную strik может попасть несколько видов текста:
 1. (любое число) **losses** in a row          (нужно достать **losses**)
 2. (любое число) **loss**                     (нужно достать **loss**)
 3. (любое число) **wins** in a row            (нужно достать **wins**)
 4. (любое число) **win**                      (нужно достать **win**)
К примеру попал первый вариант:
var strik = "7 **losses** in a row";
В переменную result нужно положить слово. Но слово, зависит от того, какой   вариант текста попал в переменную strik. В нашем случае losses. Т.е достать из 7   losses in a row только losses и положить в result. Должно стать так:
var result = "**losses**";
Соответственно, попади в var strik что то типо 4 win, в переменную result должно   попасть именно слово win.
Вариант решения задачи у меня есть, но я уверен что он дико нубский, и я что то   не знаю. (с регулярными выражениями пока что не разобрался).
Так что хочу узнать, какое решение будет самым правильным в этой задаче.

Comment: _Вариант решения задачи у меня есть_ - стоит его добавить

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно попробовать так.

```
    var text = "7 losses in a row";
    var spl = text.split(" ");
    var result = spl[1];
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Спасибо за такой быстрый ответ. На мой взгляд это самое правильное решение, хотя я над этим уже пол дня возился =)

Comment: Пожалуйста! :))

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал массив слов которые нужно искать, и брать циклом перебирать массив, и искать совпадение через `match`.

Comment: Предложение хорошее, но мне кажется не самое правильное, хотя работает, спасибо за быстрый ответ!)

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать регулярные выражения для решения этой задачи, например такой вариант:

```
var results = str.match( /\d+\s+(\w+)/i );
```

`results[1]` будет содержать необходимые данные

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно также проверять на правильность входных данных или если Вы просто перфекционист :), то можно сделать так

```
function getResult(strik) {
  if (/^\d+ losses in a row$/.test(strik))
    return 'losses';
  if (/^\d+ loss$/.test(strik))
    return 'loss';
  if (/^\d+ wins in a row$/.test(strik))
    return 'wins';
  if (/^\d+ win$/.test(strik))
    return 'win';
  return null;
}

console.log(getResult("7 losses in a row"));  //losses
console.log(getResult("4 loses in a row"));   //null
```

т.е. проверяем регулярными выражениями все варианты. Я бы сделал так :).